# Google Data Studio, comparing part year to full year

Tags: looker-studio

I'm using google Data Studio to compare full-year financial data for a number of years, sourced from a Bigquery table, on one Time series graph. I've created a separate column of data for each year so each year is one separate line on the graph. My question is simple but totally stopped me. I want to compare a part-year (2021) to 2 full-years. A time lapse graph can do that but because the current year is not complete, the line for 2021 slumps to zero and shows zero for the rest of the year (see the image, URL below). Data Studio seems to be converting null data from Bigquery for 2021 into zero and plotting zero as a result for the remainder of the year. How can I only show the part of this year (2021) vs 2 full-years without this slump. I have tried filters (and applied multiple conditions), but filtering for 2021 impacts on all other years.

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time series charts in DataStudio have the option to choose what is the desired behavior for missing data.

Just check it out in the Style tab.

[image: Time series chart, Style tab]